# Phase rule for akf triangle diagram in the field of metamorphic rock lithography

Tags: metamorphism

[image]

Why does the number of components become 3 when calculating the phase rule of rocks consisting of MS and Chl.

According to the *Goldschmidt's minimal phase* rule, in most cases, the degree of freedom of rock in the field is 2.

The component is the minimum number of components that allow the compositional mineral to form.

What is the number of components of the rock? 2 or 3?

Comment: Not my field, but I found this resource that seems pretty useful: https://serc.carleton.edu/research_education/equilibria/phaserule.html